# How Can I Group By a Range of Dates in SSRS Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, date-range

I have a list of individual subscribers to a health plan. Each subscriber has a range of dates to indicate eligibility with the plan. To help illustrate, here is a mock list of records for eligible subscribers during 2018-Q1, written in T-SQL for MS SQL Server:

```
-- qryEligibleSubscribers2018-Q1Simple

WITH
    S
AS
(
-- MOCK LIST OF SUBSCRIBERS TO HEALTH PLAN
-- WITH ELIGIBILITY TIME FRAMES
    SELECT
-- CONTINUOUSLY ELIGIBLE SINCE 2017
        '0001' AS ID,
        'MOUSE' AS LASTNAME,
        'MICKEY' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '1/1/2017' AS EFFECTIVE,
        NULL AS TERM
    UNION ALL SELECT
-- CURRENT SUBSCRIBER SINCE FEB. 2018
        '0002' AS ID,
        'MOUSE' AS LASTNAME,
        'MINNIE' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '2/1/2018' AS EFFECTIVE,
        NULL AS TERM
    UNION ALL SELECT
-- SUBSCRIBED TO PLAN FOR JAN. 2018 ONLY
        '0003' AS ID,
        'DUCK' AS LASTNAME,
        'DONALD' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '1/1/2018' AS EFFECTIVE,
        '1/31/2018' AS TERM
    UNION ALL SELECT
-- SUBSCRIBED TO PLAN STARTING IN 2018-Q2
        '0004' AS ID,
        'GOOF' AS LASTNAME,
        'GOOFY' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '4/1/2018' AS EFFECTIVE,
        NULL AS TERM
)
-- LIST OF SUBSCRIBERS
-- WHO WERE ELIGIBLE IN 2018-Q1 ONLY
SELECT
    S.ID,
    S.LASTNAME,
    S.FIRSTNAME,
    S.EFFECTIVE,
    S.TERM
FROM
    S
WHERE
-- LIMIT LIST TO 2018-Q1
    S.EFFECTIVE <= '3/31/2018'
AND
    ISNULL(S.TERM,GETDATE()) >= '1/1/2018'
```

The results, when run, are these three (out of four) subscribers:

```
ID      LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   EFFECTIVE   TERM
-----------------------------------------------------
0001    MOUSE       MICKEY      1/1/2017
0002    MOUSE       MINNIE      2/1/2018
0003    DUCK        DONALD      1/1/2018    1/31/2018
-----------------------------------------------------
```

We can see from the results that Mickey Mouse was eligible all three months for 2018-Q1, Minnie Mouse was eligible for Feb. & March only, Donald Duck was eligible for the first month of the quarter only, and Goofy came on to the plan in 2018-Q2 and so is not included in the result set.

I need to report on the total subscriber population for each month. I can do so with this more complex query, also written in T-SQL for MS-SQL Server:

```
-- qryEligibleSubscribers2018-Q1Complex

WITH
-- LIST OF MONTHS IN 2018-Q1
    R(BOR,EOR)
AS
(
-- FIXED RANGE OF MONTHS IN 2018-Q1
    SELECT
        DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,'1/1/2018'),0) AS BOR,
        DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,'3/31/2018'),0) AS EOR
-- RECURSIVELY ADD A MONTH
    UNION ALL SELECT
        DATEADD(M,1,R.BOR) AS BOR,
        R.EOR
    FROM
        R
    WHERE
        R.BOR < R.EOR
),
    S
AS
(
-- MOCK LIST OF SUBSCRIBERS TO HEALTH PLAN
-- WITH ELIGIBILITY TIME FRAMES
    SELECT
-- CONTINUOUSLY ELIGIBLE SINCE 2017
        '0001' AS ID,
        'MOUSE' AS LASTNAME,
        'MICKEY' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '1/1/2017' AS EFFECTIVE,
        NULL AS TERM
    UNION ALL SELECT
-- CURRENT SUBSCRIBER SINCE FEB. 2018
        '0002' AS ID,
        'MOUSE' AS LASTNAME,
        'MINNIE' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '2/1/2018' AS EFFECTIVE,
        NULL AS TERM
    UNION ALL SELECT
-- SUBSCRIBED TO PLAN FOR JAN. 2018 ONLY
        '0003' AS ID,
        'DUCK' AS LASTNAME,
        'DONALD' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '1/1/2018' AS EFFECTIVE,
        '1/31/2018' AS TERM
    UNION ALL SELECT
-- SUBSCRIBED TO PLAN STARTING IN 2018-Q2
        '0004' AS ID,
        'GOOF' AS LASTNAME,
        'GOOFY' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '4/1/2018' AS EFFECTIVE,
        NULL AS TERM
),
    X
AS
(
-- EXTENDED LIST OF SUBSCRIBERS
-- WHO WERE ELIGIBLE IN 2018-Q1 ONLY
-- LISTING EACH MONTH OF ELIGIBILITY
    SELECT
        R.BOR AS MONTH,
        FORMAT(R.BOR,'MMMM yyyy') AS LABEL,
        S.ID,
        S.LASTNAME,
        S.FIRSTNAME,
        S.EFFECTIVE,
        S.TERM
    FROM
        S
    INNER JOIN
        R
    ON
        S.EFFECTIVE < DATEADD(M,1,R.BOR)
    AND
        ISNULL(S.TERM,GETDATE()) >= R.BOR
)
SELECT
    X.LABEL AS MONTH,
    COUNT(X.ID) AS TOTAL
FROM
    X
GROUP BY
    X.LABEL,
    X.MONTH
ORDER BY
    X.MONTH
```

The results, when run, show that a total of two subscribers were eligible for each month in Q1:

```
MONTH       TOTAL
-----------------
January 2018    2
February 2018   2
March 2018      2
-----------------
```

To see the detailed/unaggregated results -- specifically, which subscriber was eligible during which months, we can run this query (also written in T-SQL for MS-SQL Server):

```
-- qryEligibleSubscribers2018-Q1Detailed

WITH
-- LIST OF MONTHS IN 2018-Q1
    R(BOR,EOR)
AS
(
-- FIXED RANGE OF MONTHS IN 2018-Q1
    SELECT
        DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,'1/1/2018'),0) AS BOR,
        DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,'3/31/2018'),0) AS EOR
-- RECURSIVELY ADD A MONTH
    UNION ALL SELECT
        DATEADD(M,1,R.BOR) AS BOR,
        R.EOR
    FROM
        R
    WHERE
        R.BOR < R.EOR
),
    S
AS
(
-- MOCK LIST OF SUBSCRIBERS TO HEALTH PLAN
-- WITH ELIGIBILITY TIME FRAMES
    SELECT
-- CONTINUOUSLY ELIGIBLE SINCE 2017
        '0001' AS ID,
        'MOUSE' AS LASTNAME,
        'MICKEY' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '1/1/2017' AS EFFECTIVE,
        NULL AS TERM
    UNION ALL SELECT
-- CURRENT SUBSCRIBER SINCE FEB. 2018
        '0002' AS ID,
        'MOUSE' AS LASTNAME,
        'MINNIE' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '2/1/2018' AS EFFECTIVE,
        NULL AS TERM
    UNION ALL SELECT
-- SUBSCRIBED TO PLAN FOR JAN. 2018 ONLY
        '0003' AS ID,
        'DUCK' AS LASTNAME,
        'DONALD' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '1/1/2018' AS EFFECTIVE,
        '1/31/2018' AS TERM
    UNION ALL SELECT
-- SUBSCRIBED TO PLAN STARTING IN 2018-Q2
        '0004' AS ID,
        'GOOF' AS LASTNAME,
        'GOOFY' AS FIRSTNAME,
        '4/1/2018' AS EFFECTIVE,
        NULL AS TERM
)
-- EXTENDED LIST OF SUBSCRIBERS
-- WHO WERE ELIGIBLE IN 2018-Q1 ONLY
-- LISTING EACH MONTH OF ELIGIBILITY
SELECT
    FORMAT(R.BOR,'MMMM yyyy') AS LABEL,
    S.ID,
    S.LASTNAME,
    S.FIRSTNAME,
    S.EFFECTIVE,
    S.TERM
FROM
    S
INNER JOIN
    R
ON
    S.EFFECTIVE < DATEADD(M,1,R.BOR)
AND
    ISNULL(S.TERM,GETDATE()) >= R.BOR
ORDER BY
    R.BOR,
    S.ID
```

The detailed, month-by-month results are:

```
MONTH           ID      LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   EFFECTIVE   TERM
---------------------------------------------------------------------
January 2018    0001    MOUSE       MICKEY      1/1/2017
January 2018    0003    DUCK        DONALD      1/1/2018    1/31/2018
February 2018   0001    MOUSE       MICKEY      1/1/2017
February 2018   0002    MOUSE       MINNIE      2/1/2018
March 2018      0001    MOUSE       MICKEY      1/1/2017
March 2018      0002    MOUSE       MINNIE      2/1/2018
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With the original, simple query, the result set delivers three records, one for each eligible subscriber over the entire date range of interest (2018-Q1.)

```
ID      LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   EFFECTIVE   TERM
-----------------------------------------------------
0001    MOUSE       MICKEY      1/1/2017
0002    MOUSE       MINNIE      2/1/2018
0003    DUCK        DONALD      1/1/2018    1/31/2018
-----------------------------------------------------
```

With the more complex, detailed query, the result set delivers six records, one for each month in which the subscriber was eligible for that specific month in the quarter of interest.

```
MONTH           ID      LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   EFFECTIVE   TERM
---------------------------------------------------------------------
January 2018    0001    MOUSE       MICKEY      1/1/2017
January 2018    0003    DUCK        DONALD      1/1/2018    1/31/2018
February 2018   0001    MOUSE       MICKEY      1/1/2017
February 2018   0002    MOUSE       MINNIE      2/1/2018
March 2018      0001    MOUSE       MICKEY      1/1/2017
March 2018      0002    MOUSE       MINNIE      2/1/2018
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In practice, we have several hundreds of thousands of subscribers. To use the more complex query delivers an unwieldy result set (for example, over a 12-month period, each of the hundreds of thousands of records could be mulitiplied up to 12 times ... one for each month.) I need to keep my simple query as the engine that drives my SSRS report. Using the simple result set ...:

```
ID      LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   EFFECTIVE   TERM
-----------------------------------------------------
0001    MOUSE       MICKEY      1/1/2017
0002    MOUSE       MINNIE      2/1/2018
0003    DUCK        DONALD      1/1/2018    1/31/2018
-----------------------------------------------------
```

... I can't seem to figure out how, in SSRS, to build a report that would deliver a month-by-month aggregate count of subscribers. In other words, I want and need SSRS Reporting Services to do the work in multiplying/splitting/duplicating the records into the respective eligible months, and not the underlying SQL query:

```
MONTH       TOTAL
-----------------
January 2018    2
February 2018   2
March 2018      2
-----------------
```

The essence of the issue is figuring out, if at all possible, how to split up and group over a date range in SSRS, as I am doing in the more complex SQL queries.

I've tried using various flavors of Lookup() in Report Builder, but these require a one-to-one match, for example, MultiLookup() retrieves a set of values from a dataset for name-value pairs where each pair has a 1-to-1 relationship.

In my example, a specific month in the quarter must match a specific month (within a range of months) in the subscriber set. Here, as we can see in the simple query, a subscriber can be eligible over a range of months. I believe I could successfully build an SSRS report in Report Builder if there existed some variation of Lookup() which turned on whether a specific key in one dataset (for example, January 2018) existed within a range of keys in another dataset (August 2016 - May 2018) as opposed to an exact, 1-to-1 match.

The format of the results is immaterial. Could be a chart or tablix. Just looking to get the results, if possible, for now.

Comment: Why does the whole report have to be based on one dataset?  You will see significant performance benefits having multiple datasets that return just the data required to render the different elements of the report, even if multiple elements are based on the same source data.

Comment: And re-reading your question, what is wrong with using the more complex query as your dataset source?  Just aggregate the results you have above in the query itself and return the aggregates?

Comment: It would be possible to group using extra fields in your original dataset and then expressions in the report, however the best performance will be achieved by aggregating in SQL as you already have.

Answer (score 0):

No - unfortunately I can't think of an easy way for SSRS to group by months and calculate each like you need.

If you just want to avoid running multiple queries, what might work for your situation is using a **temp table**.

Your first dataset would put the detail data in a temp table and SELECT the detail from the table.

The second dataset would use the detail temp table in the first dataset to summarize your monthly totals. You would need to enter the field name manually in the **Fields** tab for datasets that use a temp table created in a previous dataset.

Check the **Use Single Transaction** box in the **Data SOURCE** properties so it retains the temp table.

Comment: I will give it a try. Many thanks for sharing your insights!